# Regex query, description

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regex query for password verification, the rules are password must be between 8-15 chars, 1number + 1 special characters. It is working perfectly in web form.

I only need to understand it fully. If anyone can help me in describing this regex group by group,, it will be of great help to me. I do understand some part but not all.

```
^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*])[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*]{7,15}$
```

Comment: The regex shown doesn't do what you say it does. It also requires at least one lowercase letter and one uppercase letter. Have a look at [a regex guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) and read about lookaheads.

Comment: There's a cool site for regex testing: [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/vsNNwO/1). You can see 'Explanation' on the right.

Comment: Sorry, I updated the regex.

Comment: @raju now it seem to do what you described, except that the length is 7-15. So what is your question?

Comment: @AlexM, I could not understand the second group , (?=.*[!@#$%^&*]). What it actually does.

Comment: It's `posivite lookahead` for presence of any character from `!`, `@`, `#`, `$`, `%`, `^`, `&`, `*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you updated the regex...

`^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*])[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*]{7,15}$`

`^(?=.*[0-9])` from the start of the string, match any numbers. The lookahead `?=` prevents the regex from continuing if nothing matches.

`(?=.*[!@#$%^&*])` match any special characters in the group.

`[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*]` capture all letters, numbers, and special characters. At least 7 and up to 15 until the end of the line.

Comment: What do you mean by "This does not verify that there is a number."? It actually does, doesn't it?

Comment: `(?=...)` is a lookahead, not a capturing group.

Comment: This regex does check the presence of special characters and numbers. I checked it in my JS code.

Comment: Updated! I was looking at the last group, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir.